# Customizing layout of raido buttons in Shiny

Tags: shiny, radio-button

I have a set of several radio button and would like the ability to customize the layout more detailed, I know you can choose vertical or horizontal layout but I would like to combine the two. What I currently have is shown in the below picture, is it possible to keep the first 5 buttons in the same vertical column, then make the next set of 5 buttons in a vertical column to the right of the first 5, and then the last 2 in a third column to the right of those 5?

[image]

Current code:

```
radioButtons("b_Bet_Sizes", "",
                                choiceNames = list("17.5%", "35%", "62.5%", "75%", "90%", "125%", "150%", "175%","300%","400%","geo2","geo3"),
                                choiceValues = c(0.175,0.35, 0.625, 0.75, 0.9,1.25,1.5,1.75,3,4,"geo2","geo3")
                                ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with `CSS` to meet your needs.  Try this

```
css <- "
.shiny-options-group { 
  height: 100px;
  width: 600px;
  -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
    -moz-column-count: 3;    /* Firefox */ 
    
    row-count: 5;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-fill: auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
} 

.control-label {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

div.radio {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
"

radioLab <-list(tags$div(align = 'left', 
                         class = 'multicol', 
                         radioButtons("b_Bet_Sizes", "",
                                      choiceNames = list("17.5%", "35%", "62.5%", "75%", "90%", "125%", "150%", "175%","300%","400%","geo2","geo3"),
                                      choiceValues = c(0.175,0.35, 0.625, 0.75, 0.9,1.25,1.5,1.75,3,4,"geo2","geo3")
                         ), style = "font-size:75%")) 


ui <- shinyUI(
  navbarPage("TITLE",
             
             tabPanel("TABULATE",
                      tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css))),
                      fluidRow(    
                        column(width = 6, radioLab, align = "center"),
                        column(6)
                      )
             )))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: That worked, thanks! Is there any way to make the font larger? Do you also know a resource where I could learn what all this means and how to write some CSS myself?

Comment: I realized actually, I just need the CSS <- code and the "tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css))),". Then it works with my old radiobuttons code (and the size of the font is the same).

Comment: Try [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/) for more on `CSS`.